# sequelize access relations in models functions

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, models, eager-loading

I have two tables in my database "modules" and "composants". modules can have many composants and have an int attribute "prix". I wouls like to create a pseudo attribute "prix" to module which adds all attributes "prix" of its composants. How can I access the associated composants inside the function creating the pseudo attribute ?

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    "use strict";
    var module = sequelize.define('module', {
        id_module: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        nom: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        coupe: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        gamme: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        prix: {
            type     : DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            get      : function(models)  {
                var prix;
                console.log(this);
                return prix;
            }
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                module.hasMany(models.caracteristique_module,{
                    hooks: true,
                    onDelete: 'cascade',
                    foreignKey: "id_caracteristique"
                });
                module.hasMany(models.composant, {
                    through: models.composition,
                    hooks: true,
                    onDelete: 'cascade',
                    foreignKey: "id_composant"
                })
            }
        },
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'modules'
    });
    return module;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution.
in the model

```
prix: {
            type     : DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            get      : function()  {
                var prix = 0;
                if(this.composants != undefined){
                    this.composants.forEach(function(composants){
                        prix += parseInt(composants.prix);
                    });
                }
                return prix;
            }
        }
```